# android:textAllCaps=“false” not working for com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-tablayout

I have set android:textAllCaps="false" in my com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem thought it is showing the Tab Title in All caps only.

How can I remove all caps?

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/TabWeekly"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Weekly"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTextAppearanceTab" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/TabMonthly"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Monthly"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTextAppearanceTab" />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

even I have set style for it

```
<style name="CustomTextAppearanceTab" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
       <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
       <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

but its not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

custom style

```
  <style name="customTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

tab layout xml code

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    style="@style/customTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I changed  <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item> to  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item> .and it worked .Thank you very much for your response

Comment: The parent style are **wrong**. You should use `Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout` for the tabs and `TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button` for the `tabTextAppearance`

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that `TabLayout` is using the same text appearance as `Button`.

First, add a new text appearance:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MyApplication.Button" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Second, apply it as a `textAppearanceButton` in the application theme:

```
<item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.MyApplication.Button</item>
```

Of course, this solution works unless you want to keep `textAllCaps` for `Button`.